# Projecting a curve on a smooth compact manifold

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Let $M\subset\Bbb R^n$ be a compact $C^k$ ($k\geqslant 1$) manifold and let $\gamma:(0,1)\to\Bbb R^n$ be a curve of class $C^k$ which is contained in a tubular neighborhood of $M$. Let $\alpha(t)\in M$ be the point minimizing the distance from $\gamma(t)$ to $M$. Then, is $\alpha$ an almost everywhere $C^k$ curve or at least an differentiable almost everywhere curve?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems you assume (but do not state) that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Why should $\alpha(t)$ be unique?

Comment: I've just adjusted that, $M$ is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n.$ By Tubular Neighborhood Theorem, $\alpha(t)$ is unique.

Comment: Consider $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. You can find a tubular neigborhood of $S^1$ which contains $0$. What if $\gamma(t) = 0$? You have a strong deformation retraction $r : U \to M$ for any tubular neighborhood $U$ of $M$. Perhaps you should consider $r \circ \gamma$.

Comment: If $M$ is not connected, then you may even have $\alpha(t)$ in the wrong component of $M$.

Comment: I do not know a tubular neighborhood of $\Bbb S^1$ that contains $0.$ And I do not understand the phrase "If $M$ is not connected, then you may even have $\alpha(t)$ in the wrong component of $M$." What is a wrong component?

Comment: A tubular neighborhood of $M$ is an open neighborhood $U$ of $M$ which admits a $C^k$-diffeomorphism $\phi : U \to \nu M$ to the normal bundle $\nu M$ of $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\phi \mid_M$ is the zero-section. Tubular neighborhoods are not unique. Each open annulus $A$ containing $S^1$ is tubular neigborhood, and you can deform it so that the resulting $A'$ contains $0$.

Comment: Now let $M$ be the union of two circles $S, S'$ with radius $1$ and centers $a = (0,0)$ and $a' =(3,0)$. The open annulus with center $a$ and radii $0.5$ and $1.75$ is a tubular neighborhood of $S$, the open annulus with center $a'$ and radii $0.5$ and $1.25$ is a tubular neighborhood of $S'$. These annuli are disjoint and their union is a tubular neighborhood of $M$. What about $\alpha(t)$ if $\gamma(t) = 1.7 e^{i\pi t}$?